Identify this set: red megablocks car-like parts

I found these pieces in a used box of MegaBloks, and I think they belong together in a set that builds a car or something like that.

Please add a picture of the pieces, without one we can't do anything.

Hi Ben and welcome to Bricks.SE! As Henrik already wrote, your question can't be answered without a photo, so we have closed it until one is added. To add an image, check out the [help], especially the page about editing and formatting. The last paragraph details how to add a picture. If you're done with that, we'll reopen the question so that others can answer it. Meanwhile, please take the [tour] to learn more about the site, the community and the rules and customs here. Play well!

The piece on the right seems to have glitter in it, but the other one does not. The left one is marbled with black instead - can you confirm these?

These parts are both from the Mega Bloks Halo Red USNC Spade playset:

Found by searching for "mega bloks red car" and browsing the image results.

If I could "+2" for "also including my methodology" I would ;)

@Zhaph-BenDuguid "give fish" AND "teach how to fish" :)
